# Facebook share not getting image in wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, wordpress-theming

one small issue with wordpress:

1. few meta tags of `og:` are repeating means twice on page
2. when sharing on facebook image now showing in facebook share..

if some one can help please reply

Comment: Are you using featured image in your theme ?

Comment: no, I am not using any featured image for that post.

Answer (score 0):

Use feature image in you theme

```
function ST4FB_header() {
    global $post;
    $post_description = ST4_get_FB_description($post);
    $post_featured_image = ST4_get_FB_image($post->ID);
    if ( (is_single()) AND ($post_featured_image) AND ($post_description) ) {
?>
  <meta name="title" content="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" />
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $post_description; ?>" />
  <link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $post_featured_image; ?>" />
<?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ST4FB_header');
```

And write this function for more info http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/share-your-posts-on-facebook-with-a-preview-image-and-a-description/

Comment: is there any other way of doing it?